# array move when a duplicate exists in an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code.= with a newbie experience in php

```
$values   =  array(
                   array('field'   =>  1),
                   array('field'   =>  2),
                   array('field'   =>  2),
                   array('field'   =>  3),
                   array('field'   =>  4),
                   array('field'   =>  4),
                   );

print_r($values);
foreach($values as $k => $v) { 
      //Check for duplicate
      //Move the value "field" to another part of the array which has no equal value on range of index 2 

}
```

?>
A code that moves an array if it founds a duplicate within 2 indexes until it reach the without duplicate.

My expected results will be: Can be different results which satisfies the conduction given.

```
 1.   Array(
                [0] => Array('field'   =>  4),
                       Array('field'   =>  2),
                       Array('field'   =>  1),
                       Array('field'   =>  4),
                       Array('field'   =>  3),
                       Array('field'   =>  2)
                       );
 2.   Array(
                [0] => Array('field'   =>  2),
                       Array('field'   =>  1),
                       Array('field'   =>  4),
                       Array('field'   =>  3),
                       Array('field'   =>  2),
                       Array('field'   =>  4)
                       );
```

I want to use array_splice and array_unique but dont know how to start. Maybe its a while loop instead of foreach. Finding a duplicate and move the value if found duplicate with the index of 2. Please help me.

Comment: You mean - move duplicates at the end of the array?

Comment: not really. example if duplicate is found within the range of the 2 rows it will move to another index. example ['field'] => 1, ['field'] => 1, ['field'] => 2. 2nd value will move to the third index. e.g ['field'] => 1, ['field'] => 2, ['field'] => 1

Comment: You mean - 'Separate' keys with same values?

Comment: yes @quantme. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try [sorting array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). This could do the job, is not perfect but is a good point to start):

```
<?php
$values   =  array(
  array('field'   =>  1),
  array('field'   =>  1),
  array('field'   =>  2),
  array('field'   =>  2),
  array('field'   =>  2),
  array('field'   =>  3),
  array('field'   =>  3),
  array('field'   =>  4),
  array('field'   =>  4),
);

print_r($values);
uksort($values, create_function('$x,$y','return ($y === $x) ? -1 : 1;'));
print_r($values);
?>
```

I don't know how diverse are your values, good luck.

Comment: how about fourth movements. placing the duplicate to the fourth iterations? it works only on two iterations how about many?